Automatic unsafe authorization with React Native
I am trying to create a simple login/out functionality for my customer's app with React Native. Login functionality is structured by the following rules:

Initial login should be implemented with basic auth (login + password)
On successful login I make the second request to the client's server and with response X-CSRF-TOKEN value is returned
That token is used for further requests (mainly POSTING data to customer's SAP server).

Login auth request (no cookies or tokens are stored in the app's memory manually):
...

var post_headers = new Headers();

post_headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(credentials.login + ':' + credentials.password));
post_headers.append('X-Csrf-Token', 'Fetch');

let response = await fetch(serverReasons, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: post_headers
})

...

The problem is when logging out and logging in again even with wrong credentials server will still accept request as the previous user is still there. I suspect that has something to do with the way my client's server handles sessions but I am not sure (since I am not so wise in the ways of CSRF) and want to ask if there's any way I can handle that type of behavior?
Reinstalling app solves the issue - login is required again and server responds to wrong credentials with 403. But on successful login wrong behavior repeats (almost as if server keeps client info and links it with token or something).
I tried to manage problem with local cookies and delete them when logging out, testing all sorts of requests (no token, no credentials) - server will still authorize me.
UPD
Logging out process involves following steps:

Removing active user from the configuration SQLite database
Returning to the auth screen

I do not send any logout request to the server (there is no endpoint from my client to invalidate active session or anything like that)

If you logout and login again with wrong credentials and still getting back the previous user's data, I think you might have something wrong with how you logout. Can you edit the post and describe how your logout function works? Edit: It also might be because your server is maintaining a session for the user even after you logout.
